# File on FreeNAS share is locked by another user?

Tags: freenas

What can I do when files on FreeNAS shares are locked by another user? Is there anyway that I can force to unlock the file from other users?

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted on FreeNAS forums, there are two ways to solve this problem [forum](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/being-an-evil-cifs-admin.23099/):

1. You can kill the whole user smbstatus to check who has the file open and kill the PID session.
2. You can Computer Management on Windows, find out the file open and kill the connection to the file.